# Getting odd results when trying to solve Collatz p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m

Tags: c++, collatz

I'm trying to solving Project Euler [Problem 14](https://projecteuler.net/problem=14).  It asks to find the number under 1 million that generates the longest sequence.  What I did was create a vector, v, and populate its elements with the length of the sequence for a particular number.  Thus, the element that resides in position 13 will correspond to the length of the sequence generated by the number 13, and so on.  However, some seemingly random elements take very large numbers and I can't figure out what's wrong with the code.  Also, when I test it with 1,000,000, I get a completely wrong answer, but I know the program is working for some small numbers after testing them by hand and verifying.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void find_longest(int n)
{
    int count = 1;
    int max = 0;
    int position;

    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(0);
    v.push_back(0);

    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        long long int trainer = i;
        count = 1;
        while(trainer != 1)
        {
            if(trainer%2 == 0)
            {
                trainer /= 2;
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                trainer = 3*trainer + 1;
                count++;
            }
        }
        v.push_back(count);
    }

    vector<int>::iterator it;

    for(it = v.begin(); it < v.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << v[*it] << endl;
        //if(v[*it] > max)
        //{
        //    max = v[*it];
        //    position = *it;
        //}
    }

    //cout << "The longest sequence is " << max << " terms long and is ";
    //cout << "generated by the number " << position << "." << endl;
}

int main()
{
    find_longest(100);
    //find_longest(1000000);
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing where you store the overall maximum total. I see "max" at the top of your code,  but I never see "count" overwriting "max" if "count" > "max".

Comment: isn't `*it` the number? Not `v[*it]`?

Comment: Also, I'm confused why you're storing anything within a vector<>. I believe you should just store "max" and "value" for the starting number that created the longest sequence.

Comment: I commented out the part where I find max within the vector using the iterator; I believe it works correctly, but I may be wrong.  @JohnCorbett, the number that generates a particular sequence is *it, correct.  The actual sequence length would be v[*it], wouldn't it?

Comment: No, the argument to operator[] is an index, not an iterator. What you need is `max = *it`, and the `position` will be distance between `v.begin()` and current iterator, e.g. `position = std::distance(v.begin(), it);` What `v[*it]` does is index into vector with value that iterator refers to. It's wrong logic.

Comment: That said, you don't need a vector, really. Just store a running max inside your first for loop.

Comment: I get the correct answer when I add a simple if-statement to the for-loop to find the max/position.  But I wanted to get more creative and use a vector for reasons I didn't specify.  I think I understand now @jrok, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: You're welcome. Oh, and there's a neat algorithm in standard library to find a maximum value in a range: `max = std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end());` It's in `<algorithm>` header.

Comment: Cool! I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//removing change for type mismatch

You don't need to remember all N numbers in a vector. 
All you need is current sequence length. Then you calculate sequence length for the next number and if it is bigger than what you have already, you just keep the biggest one.

Comment: Nope, not enough even in 64 bit OS-es. sizeof(int) is always 32 bit.
In both LLP64 and LP64 int is defined as 32 bit.

Comment: @artapet Not all int's are 32 bits.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/size-of-int-long-etc

Comment: Also, I'm not understanding why 1,000,000 wouldn't fit in 2^31 : 2,147,483,648?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, 32 bit is enough.